# Unique slug in editing with form request update method Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm having a hard time with this update method. I have a slug field in my news model and it has to be unique. When I update sometimes I may not want to change the slug but the validation of Laravel doesn't let me send my data and when I bypass the validation MySQL won't let me insert into the slug field because of duplicate. This is my update method and validation I have a handleRequest which is just to validate images being uploaded.

NewsController

```
public function update(CreateNewsRequest $request, $id)
{
        $news = News::findOrFail($id);    
        $data = $this->handleRequest($request);              
        $news->update($data);

    return redirect(route('admin.access.news.index'))->with('message', 'Your news has been updated');
}
```

CreateNewsRequest

```
 public function authorize()
{
    //if(access()->hasRole(1) || access()->hasRole(2))
    return true;
}


 public function rules(){     

$news = $this->route()->parameter('news');

$rules = [
    'title' => 'required',
    'slug' => 'required|unique:news',
    'excerpt' => 'required',
    'body' => 'required',
    'category_id' => 'required',
    'image' => 'mimes:gif,bmp,jpeg,jpg,png',
];
    
    switch($this->method()){
    case 'PUT':
    case 'PATCH':
        $rules['slug'] = 'required|unique:news,slug,' .$news;
        break;
    }

return $rules;
}

}
```

I put this function in NewsController for now

```
private function handleRequest($request)
{
    if(! $request->published_at ){
            $request->published_at = null;
        }
        
    $data = $request->all();

    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        
        $image = $request->file('image');          
        $fileName = $image->getClientOriginalName();            
        $destination = public_path(config('cms.image.directory'));                      
        $successUploaded = $image->move($destination, $fileName);
        
        if($successUploaded)
        {
            $width = config('cms.image.thumbnail.width');
            $height = config('cms.image.thumbnail.height');
            $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $thumbnail = str_replace(".{$extension}", "_thumb.{$extension}", $fileName);
            Image::make($destination . '/' . $fileName)
                        ->resize($width, $height)
                        ->save($destination . '/' . $thumbnail);
        }
        $data['image'] = $fileName;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AndriyLozynskiy Editing works! Turns out I had a mistake in the form thanks for the help.

I also changed the validation a bit and created an UpdateFormRequest.php

```
 public function rules(Request $request){

    $news = $this->route('news');

        $rules = [
            'title' => 'required',
            'excerpt' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'image' => 'mimes:gif,bmp,jpeg,jpg,png',
            'slug' => ($request->slug != $this->slug) ? 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:news,slug' : ''
        ];

        return $rules;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should ignore your current model by `id` not by other fields that can be changed in update form. Try this:

```
switch($this->method()){
    case 'PUT':
    case 'PATCH':
        $id = $this->route('id');
        $rules['slug'] = 'required|unique:news,slug,'.$id;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I just tried whit this method and it still doesnt let me insert in the DB I don't even get to the point where mysql throws me out because of a duplicate entry, i just deleted that key fornow trying to focus on being able to update properly;

Comment: @DavidDacruz try to `dd($id)` i'm not sure if this is the right way to get current model id.

Comment: I will keep trying Thanks again !

Comment: dd($id) gives me null when I do route('news') I get 1 so i tried again but i still get slug duplicate stopped error :)

Comment: make `php artisan route:list ` and look what is name of parameter in your update url. For example if it looks like  `news/{news_id}` you can get this parameter by name in your custom form request like `$this->route('news_id')`.

Comment: That's what my routes show,PUT|PATCH | admin/access/news/{news}                    

I put $this->route('news') but it did not work

Comment: dd($rules['slug']); show me this "required|unique:news,slug,1" I have no idea where this 1 is coming from ?

Comment: This is the url  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/access/news/1?test

wich returns "required|unique:news,slug," when i die and dump

Comment: It's ok your validation rule for slug looks good. but i noticed that error says `Duplicate entry 'any-slug' ` but you validate field with name `slug`

Comment: That was actually the post title wich then gets the whitespaces replaced widh dashes sorry about the confusion when i tested i named me post any slug because it wasn't worrying still isn't .. ^^

Comment: The slug has already been taken.its not even a db error it's a validation message

Comment: are you sure you don't have other records in your news table with the same slug  you trying to save?

Comment: Absolutly sure i deleted every news record i only have one at the moment i created using the form so the store method works fine but i cain't edit because The slug has already been taken.but I would like to be able to edit a record with or without changing the slug while requiring it to remain unique in the database I tried with if statement in the controller before cleaning up and posting for some help here

Comment: Ok so i just tried changing the slug and updating with the only record I have I get these two queries 

    `select count(*) as aggregate from news where slug = 'testa' and     id <> 1 and

select * from news where news.id = '1' limit 1` yes it is 1 :)

Comment: But i get a 404 error No query results for model [App\Models\News\News]

OH my bad i see it's trying to find where testa is but that is my renamed slug so it doesn't exist and when i try to update it without changing the slug it just won't let me pass validation

Comment: I'm still at it if anyone can help save the night ! Thanks ahead